# How do i get the current App version user x is using? (android)

Tags: android

Does someone have a method that enables me to get the current App version user X is currently using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String versionname = " ver-" + getApplicationContext()
                            .getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                            getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
String versioncode = " ver-" + getApplicationContext()
                            .getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                            getPackageName(), 0).versionCode;
```

If You are in activity you can directly access

```
String versionname = " ver-" + getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                            getPackageName(), 0).versionName);
String versioncode = " ver-" + getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                            getPackageName(), 0).versionCode);
```

Comment: no need for the String.valueOf() and I also removed redundant brackets.

Comment: Cannot resolve method getPackageManager()

Comment: you are so new I said already if you are not in activity then use the first otherwise second

Comment: I am sorry but I don't get what you are criticizing. I never edited the question. I simplified the code of this answer by removing redundant parts that will cause more issues for beginners as they might wonder why there is a need to use `String.valueOf()` or an extra pair of brackets. I also don't see how I can see that a user is having issues with the code when I am the first to comment/edit on the answer. I can't look into the future and I just simplified the code. I would do it again...

Comment: @GeorgeStocker sorry, I forgot you ping you...

Comment: @WarrenFaith I goofed here, I thought I was looking at the question, but I was in fact, looking at an answer. Carry on. Sorry 'bout that.

Answer (score 0):

I know there is an application version in Manifest file. Depends where you want to know his version, you can create a web service call in the android to send the user version..

Comment: i want to insert the app version in a sqlight database and send it via json to my sql server - the only thing i need right now is a way to get the app version user x is using

Comment: I think you can instantiate the sqlight with the version when the user install the application. Then it is simple to select it and sent via json to server..

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;

PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
version = pInfo.versionName; // use versionCode to get versioncode
```

Comment: private String AppVersion;
PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
AppVersion = pInfo.versionName;

does not work :/

"unknown class pInfo.versionName"
"Cannot resolve method 'getPackageManager"

Comment: are you using this code in Activity or somewhere else ?

Comment: im using it in an Activity